# Changing $PATH variable in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have NGINX installed in the directory /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx

[root@SPK-D-0271 ~]# nginx -t
-bash: nginx: command not found

[root@SPK-D-0271 ~]# which nginx
/usr/bin/which: no nginx in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)

[root@SPK-D-0271 ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

I think if I can change the $PATH variable to /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx the nginx -t command will work for me.

Where can I change this $PATH variable?

Answer (score 0):

Set the path in `~/.profile` and add

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
```